# How to prevent OSX from putting a computer to sleep when a VM is running in VMWare Fusion

Tags: macos, sleep, vmware-fusion

I have discovered the hard way that bad things happen to my VMs if my macbook pro goes to sleep while a VM is running.

Is there a way to prevent my computer from being put to sleep when VMWare Fusion is running a VM but allow it to be put to sleep otherwise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To paraphrase the iPhone ads, there's an app for that: [Caffeine](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/24120/caffeine)

It is a menubar app. Click prevents computer from sleeping, click again and the computer can sleep like normal.

Answer (score 6):

Leave it plugged into the power adapter, and set this in System Preferences -> Energy Saver.

[image: Power Adapter Settings]

When its on battery, set it to sleep after however long you want.

This might not be the exact solution you're looking for, but I don't know of any software that will automatically handle this without some kind of intervention. Apps like [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/) or [InsomniaX](http://semaja2.net/insomniaxinfo) require **doing** something and can be easily forgotten.

Comment: VM Fusion seems to be ignoring this setting and sleeps the VMs anyway.  May be a bug in VMWare fusion 4.